# CSS performance drop down

Tags: css

What can be a reson of performance drop down. The more times hover starts the greater the delay ... after a few hovers on the animation I have to wait a few seconds.

```
.post_featured_content{
   opacity:0;

  -webkit-transition: all ease .3s;
  -moz-transition: all ease .3s;
  -o-transition: all ease .3s;
  transition: all ease .3s;
}

.header_featured_posts .featured_item_inner:hover .post_featured_content{
    opacity:1;
}
```

Do I make some stupid mistake?

Ps. I must wait even for hover without transition effect

Comment: too few code to say... try animating `opacity` instead of `all`

Comment: Sounds like it's related to something else on the page, probably your Javascript.

Comment: Yep, something in JS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certain changes can be costly on the browser. Basically the only things that can be changed and transitioned/animated quickly are:

- Position (using transform)
- Scale
- Rotation
- Opacity

Your example only uses `opacity`. This usually does not lead to performance issues. Are there any other properties being changed? Do they need a transition as well? If the answer's *no*, change your transition to read `transition: opacity .3s ease` instead.

If you are changing *anything else* your browser will need to re-paint the screen the whole time, which can cause performance issues.

If a part of your site is changing a lot of properties, it might be useful to include the following css:
`translate3d(0,0,0)`

This forces the GPU to create a separate layer to take care of all the changes.

For more information I suggest you take a [read here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/)

Comment: Thanks for tips... I got stupid JS bug - function that calls itself :) ... I was affraid that I will must check all CSS for performance because I never thinking about CSS performance